# How can I know process bar fully completed?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, progress-bar

I want to change the tab after my process bar fully filled up... I have a timer1 control that sets the my timer. as soon as the process bar is fully filled change the tabpage on winform application.

> Error: it doesnt change the tab after process bar is completed.

```
                 if (progressBar1.Value == progressBar1.Maximum)
                 { 
                    tabControl1.SelectedTab = result; 
                  }
```

Comment: @GrantWinney when my process bar is max than change the tabPage..

Answer (score 1):

You can just check that the `Value` property matches the `Maximum` property:

```
if (progressBar.Value == progressBar.Maximum) {
    // its done.
}
```

Comment: I used this  but didnt work?   if (progressBar1.Value == progressBar1.Maximum)
            {
                tabControl1.SelectedTab = result;
            }

Comment: So did you check if you are out the progressBar1.Maximum? I guess for your case the better solution is:  if (progressBar1.Value >= progressBar1.Maximum) {...}